# How to use in_array and isset in twig template?

Tags: php, twig

This part:

```
<?php if (isset($quantity_taxation_curr) && in_array($currency['code'], $quantity_taxation_curr)) { ?>
```

to become in twig format, I tried with this:

```
{% if isset(quantity_taxation_curr) AND in_array(currency['code'], quantity_taxation_curr) %}
```

But it's not correct.

Comment: Can't help you, but u got my upvote because of a well asked question. Thats how it should be. Keep it simple & short. Only the relevant parts of the code included, shown what you've tried so far. This is a great example of a question and I hope someone can help you out :)

Comment: It might be helpful in the long run to encapsulate this in a variable that is passed to your twig template - although it appears you _can_ do this, template logic is usually best kept as simple as possible. Something like, `quantity_transaction_curr_exists`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% if quantity_taxation_curr is defined and currency['code'] in quantity_taxation_curr %}
```

Comment: Yeah, but i have currency['code'], not just code ? can be a problem ?

Comment: @Morgan Use `currency['code']` instead `'code'`, result: `{% if quantity_taxation_curr is defined and currency['code'] in quantity_taxation_curr %}`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
{% if quantity_taxation_curr is defined and 'code' in quantity_taxation_curr %}
...
{% endif %}
```